# Sending traffic to the right URL - Amazon AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, subdomain

A question from a newbie;

I've recently bought a new domain from NameCheap, and i want to host websites with that domain on Amazon S3.
My question is, how do i go from https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/example.com to simply example.com?

Do i have to purchase the domain from Amazon or is there a workaround? I've searched far and wide, but can't seem to find any answers.

I've tried editing my DNS records @ Namecheap

I've created routes in Route 53 and also setup Cloudfront.

Comment: Setup [cloudfront](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html)

Comment: Can you be more specific about what DNS changes you made @ Namecheap? I'm asking if you moved the example.com domain to Route53 by changing the NS Record at Namecheap to point to name servers that are listed in the "example.com" Route53 hosted zone? Or something else?

If you do a `nslookup -type=NS example.com" do you get nameservers from Namecheap or Route53?

Comment: I added a CNAME record as follows - 
Host = www
Value = example.com.s3-website.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com
TTL = Automatic

URL Redirect
Host = @
Value = example.com
Unmasked

Havent tried a nslookup before, but i have now:
s3-website.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com nameserver = ns-1358.awsdns-41.org.
s3-website.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com nameserver = ns-837.awsdns-40.net.
s3-website.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com nameserver = ns-424.awsdns-53.com.
s3-website.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com nameserver = ns-2034.awsdns-62.co.uk.

Hope you can use this :-)

Comment: [Tutorial: Configuring a static website using a custom domain registered with Route 53 - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html) Using CloudFront is optional.

Comment: I'm wondering if your issue is with how your domain is setup with your registry. Namecheap is your domains registry. While this will work with S3 its a bit tricky for newbies. But if I'm not mistaken traffic needs to go to AWS in order to use S3 as a website. While you can add a CNAME for a subdomain like "www" you would need to do that in Route53. Can anyone double check my facts on that?

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit tricky for a newbie because you need traffic for [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) to go to AWS Route53. Here's a one way.

Part 1: Delegate "www.example.com" to Route53

In other words send all traffic for "www.example.com" to Route53.

1. Go to AWS Route53 and setup a hosted zone for "www.example.com".
2. Now go into that hosted zone and make note of the NS record for "www.example.com".
3. Login to the NameCheap console and add an "NS" record for "www.example.com" using the Route53 name servers from step 2 and save.
4. Wait 15 minutes to an hour, then you will be able to use `nslookup -type="NS" www.example.com` from a command line. Which should return the AWS Route53 name servers for the hosted zone you setup in AWS for "www.example.com".

Par 2: Setup S3 website

Now tell Route53 to serve traffic for your domain from CloudFront using an S3 bucket setup as a website and serving as the distribution origin.

1. While logged into the AWS console, go to Route53 and click on the hosted zone "www.example.com."
2. Add a new record and toggle the "Alias" switch, then search for your CloudFront distribution, select it and save. If you do not see your distribution, go to the distribution and check that the "Alternate domain names" list "www.example.com" then make sure there is a origin with the S3 bucket set as the "Origin domain"
3. Make sure your bucket has an inline policy that grants public access while testing (unless your an IAM pro, then in that case lock it down to CloudFront).
4. Once pages are working please update the S3 bucket inline policy to only allow the CloudFront distribution.

NOTES:

An AWS Alias record is special to AWS (I think its a special type of CNAME that only route53 can handle). It has to be an alias because now that "www.example.con" is a hosted zone its is also now an Apex domain, and you cannot make a CNAME record for any Apex domain. That's a written rule somewhere out there on the internet.

Comment: This is a lot of setup and something which I encourage the use of CloudFormation or Terraform to reduce human error. However the DNS stuff, though common, is not easy unless the domain name registries involved all has Terraform providers. So the DNS stuff usually needs to be done manually.  So even though I say that, its very understandable that people do not because that just make things even more complex.